# metodo sort() me da error inesperado, en C++ (QT)

Tags: c++, qt

Tengo una lista que guarda objetos tipo AVION y quiero ordenarla por uno de sus parámetros tipo float descendentemente.

En una clase llamada aeropuerto tengo una static list flotaAviones, en la cual, en una parte del programa le lleno todos los datos.

Código de la función que imagino esta errónea:

```
bool Avion::mayor(const Avion&A, const Avion&B)
{
    return A.porcientoCapacidadOcupada > B.porcientoCapacidadOcupada;
}
void Avion::ordenarFlota()
{
Aeropuerto *obj =new Aeropuerto();
    obj->flotaAviones.sort(mayor);
}
```

El error que me lanza es > D

> :\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\list.tcc:385:
>
> ```
> error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '__comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* __comp) (...)'
>         if (__comp(*__first2, *__first1))
>               ^
> ```

No se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Sospecho que el problema está en la función `sort` de `flotaAviones` ¿puedes mostrarnos esa función?

Comment: la funcion sort de flotaAviones es la que viene con el lenguaje, o sea el list.sort() podria mandarte donde me direcciona el programa cuando le doy clic al error, pero no es mi codigo , sino la estructura de la clase list,  eso es lo que deseas ver?

Comment: Esa lista ¿es una lista de la STL (`std::list`) o es una lista de Qt? ¿Cuál es el tipo de `flotaAviones`?

Comment: cuando le doy doble clic al error me lleva a list.tcc

if (__comp(*__first2, *__first1))
  {
    iterator __next = __first2;
    _M_transfer(__first1, __first2, ++__next);
    __first2 = __next;
  }

Comment: Haz que la función `mayor` sea estática ¿te desaparece el error?

Comment: @Trauma 
.h
class Aeropuerto
{
(...)
 static list <Avion> flotaAviones;

}

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus paula, efectivamente, puse en la .h la funcion mayor como static y no da el error, muchas gracias, ponlo como respuesta para votarte, no me deja en modo comentario

Comment: La respuesta es compleja @HOLDTHEDOOR y no puedo responder ahora :'(

Answer (score 0):

Estás llamando a la función [`sort` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) de una lista de la STL, su firma es la siguiente:

```
template< class Compare > 
void sort( Compare comp );
```

Es decir, espera un comparador que usará para comparar los elementos, este comparador puede ser:

- [Un funtor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funtor): necesitarás crear una estructura que tenga el operador paréntesis sobrecargado y pasar una instancia a la función `sort`.

  ```
  struct ordenaAviones
  {
      bool operator()(const Avion&A, const Avion&B)
      {
          return A.porcientoCapacidadOcupada > B.porcientoCapacidadOcupada;
      }
  };

  void Avion::ordenarFlota()
  {
      Aeropuerto *obj =new Aeropuerto();
      obj->flotaAviones.sort(ordenaAviones{});
  }
  ```
- [Una lambda](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_lambda): Puedes usar la lambda directamente como parámetro de `sort`:

  ```
  void Avion::ordenarFlota()
  {
      Aeropuerto *obj =new Aeropuerto();
      obj->flotaAviones.sort([](const Avion&A, const Avion&B)
      { return A.porcientoCapacidadOcupada > B.porcientoCapacidadOcupada; });
  }
  ```
- Una función libre: una función libre es una función que no pertenece a ninguna clase.

  ```
  bool ordenaAviones(const Avion&A, const Avion&B)
  {
      return A.porcientoCapacidadOcupada > B.porcientoCapacidadOcupada;
  }

  void Avion::ordenarFlota()
  {
      Aeropuerto *obj =new Aeropuerto();
      obj->flotaAviones.sort(ordenaAviones);
  }
  ```

La razón por la que te ha funcionado al pasar `bool Avion::mayor(const Avion&, const Avion&)` a función estática es que las funciones estáticas de case (igual que las funciones libres) no necesitan una instancia de objeto para ser llamadas, que la falta de instancia es precisamente el error que estabas recibiendo pues le has pasado como parámetro a `sort`

```
bool(Avion::*)(const Avion&, const Avion&)
```

Un puntero a función miembro de `Avion` que devuelve `bool` y recibe dos referencias constantes a `Avion`. Para poder invocar un puntero a función miembro de clase, se necesita un puntero o instancia de la clase y llamar al operador `.*` or `->*`:

```
struct S { void f(){} };
using puntero = void(S::*)();

puntero p = &S::f;
S s;
S *ps = &s;

(s.*p)();   // Llama a S::f
(ps->*p)(); // Llama a S::f
```